# In case of RHEL based distribution how do I check which software package manager is used, using python

Tags: python, linux, rhel

In case of RHEL family distributions like RHEL, CentOS, Fedora etc, how do I check which software package manager(yum , dnf) is used, using python.

I know, I can check what is the OS, and which version, and based on version decide if dnf or yum is used.

But, it is possible to check without taking in consideration the os version.

Comment: What do you want to do once you have the version? Why do you want to check what the package manager is?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the Pythonic way of "ask for forgiveness than permission" by trying to import `dnf` module first, and if that fails, import `yum`.

And obviously, if that fails as well, then something is very wrong / no packager manager exists, etc.

```
manager = 'dnf'    
try:
    import dnf
except ImportError:
    manager = 'yum'  
    try:
        import yum 
    except ImportError:
        manager = None

print(manager)
```